# Best practice for only getting parts of the store/state in React component using redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I implemented by using redux thunk that if one component is mounted, that the store is filled by calling an API.

The data which are requested have much more fields than I need in particalur components. So could you please give me a tip what  the best practice would be to get only parts of the data. Because storing a reduced version of the data also (kind of duplication) wouldn't be a good practice, would it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you can use the [selectors](https://redux.js.org/recipes/computingderiveddata#motivation-for-memoized-selectors)

Answer (score 0):

You can deconstruct data.

For example, when you connect your component to the redux state.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    relevantPartOfTheState: state.some.part.of.the.state
}
```

This is essentially what selectors do.

> The data which are requested have much more fields than I need in particalur components

You are not required to save all of it. You can have something like this.

```
switch (action.type) {
    case RECEIVE_USELESS_DATA:
        return action.payload.onlyRelevantData
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use selectors as mentioned above or somethine like that:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    relevantPartOfTheState: fetchSliceOfReducer(state)
}
```

The fetchSliceOfReducer(state) can be a function from inside the reducer file where you take only part of the state. Obviously you have to import the function in your component file and it can be reused for other components. So if your state is something like that

```
state = {
 value: true,
 name:"Michael"
}
```

your function would be `const fetchSliceOfReducer = state => state.value`
Selectors would be more appropriate for a growing app, where as the example above is nice and neat for something smaller